# SQLAlchemy: How to use order_by based on a calculated value?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So I have the following database model:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False, unique=True)
    ...
    tasks = db.relationship('Task', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

    def number_of_tries(self):
        return Task.query.filter_by(user_id=self.id).count()

    def correct_answers(self):
        return Task.query.filter_by(user_id=self.id).filter_by(correct=True).count()

    def percentage(self):
        try:
            return '{:.2%}'.format(self.correct_answers()/self.number_of_tries())
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            return None

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.nickname)


class Task(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    task_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    correct = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%r %s>' % (self.task_id, self.correct)
```

Two tables, the first one storing User data, the second one in relation with the first, storing data about questions the User answers.

I would like to sort the users based on their success ratio, so I would do something like this:

```
User.query.order_by(User.percentage).all()
```

but it won't work. What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to use order_by based on a method like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with SqlAlchemy, you have to think in sets of objects and their values. The query you want involves three different sets: Users, their correct answers and their total answers.

Want you want is a query like that (warning, that's just a sample, you could write it much better)

```
select userid, cor_count/ans_count from users
inner join (select userid, count(*) cor_count from answers where correct=true group by userid) as correct_answers on users.userid=correct_answers.userid
inner join (select userid, count(*) as ans_count from answers group by userid) as total_answers on total_answers.userid=users.userid
where users.userid='xxxx'
order by 2
```

so, you have to formulate this (somehow) in SqlAlchemy. A guideline would by something to that effect:

```
ans_q = session.query(Task.user_id, func.count(task.id).label('cnt')).group_by(Task.user_id)
corr_ans_q = session.query(Task.user_id, func.count(task.id).label('cnt')).filter(Task.correct).group_by(Task.user_id)

ans_q = alias(ans_q.selectable)
corr_ans_q = alias(corr_ans_q.selectable)

q = session.query(User).join(ans_q,ans_q.c.user_id==User.id).join(corr_ans_q.c.user_id==User.id).order_by(corr_ans_q.c.cnt/ans_q.c.cnt)
```

Comment: So, I am pretty new to this, so I am not sure what half of the things do here, but I tried it, it runs, but it does not work (they are not ordered). [See Here](http://i.imgur.com/EV2n8Tg.png)

Comment: Ok, let's see. Try to do a str(q) so we can see the generated script.

Comment: `SELECT "user".id AS user_id, "user".nickname AS user_nickname FROM "user" JOIN (SELECT task.user_id AS task_user_id, count(task.id) AS cnt FROM task GROUP BY task.user_id) AS anon_1 ON anon_1.task_user_id = "user".id JOIN (SELECT task.user_id AS task_user_id, count(task.id) AS cnt FROM task WHERE task.correct = 1 GROUP BY task.user_id) AS non_2 ON anon_2.task_user_id = "user".id ORDER BY anon_2.cnt / anon_1.cnt`

Comment: Can you execute that query against your database ? Also, if you can, include anon_2.cnt/anon_1.cnt at your output

Comment: @lacer The fields are ints so the division result is int, so no decimal. Change func.count(task.id) to cast(func(count(task.id)), float) and it should work. Cast can be found in sqlalchemy.sql.expression

Comment: Okay so I changed the SQL code, and it works fine as you can see [here](http://i.imgur.com/INu0yJL.png) but while changing the code in python, I get a `maximum recursion depth` error. All I did was add the `cast` function.

Comment: [I can't show you above because this is all I can see all the way up](http://i.imgur.com/NHIaQCr.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76824/discussion-between-tasos-vogiatzoglou-and-lacer).

Answer (score 0):

I think that "Hybrid Attributes" will solve you problem.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#module-sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid

UPD:

```js
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Boolean, DateTime, ForeignKey

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    nickname = Column(String(64), nullable=False, unique=True)
    tasks = relationship('Task', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

    def number_of_tries(self):
        return self.tasks.count()

    def correct_answers(self):
        return self.tasks.filter_by(correct=True).count()

    def percentage(self):
        try:
            return '{:.2%}'\
                .format(float(self.correct_answers())/self.number_of_tries())
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            return None

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.nickname)


class Task(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'task'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    task_id = Column(Integer)
    correct = Column(Boolean)
    timestamp = Column(DateTime)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%r %s>' % (self.task_id, self.correct)


from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
# create a configured "Session" class
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

# create a Session
session = Session()

from datetime import datetime
task1 = Task(task_id=1, correct=True, timestamp=datetime.now())
task2 = Task(task_id=2, correct=False, timestamp=datetime.now())
task3 = Task(task_id=3, correct=False, timestamp=datetime.now())
task4 = Task(task_id=4, correct=False, timestamp=datetime.now())
task5 = Task(task_id=5, correct=True, timestamp=datetime.now())
task6 = Task(task_id=6, correct=True, timestamp=datetime.now())
user1 = User(nickname="Lekha", tasks=[task1, task2, task3])
user2 = User(nickname="Vanya", tasks=[task4, task5, task6])
session.add(user1, user2)
session.commit()

print(user1.number_of_tries())
print(user1.correct_answers())
print(user1.percentage())
```

Comment: Yes, I have found the Hybrid module also, but I still can't get it to work, I am really not sure what I should do. Would you care to eleborate?

Comment: Yes, my version can also do that, I mean I can ask for a specific user's "percentage", it works fine for that, what I can't do is ordering a query by that number. What I would like to do is, create a TOP5 based on these methods. With any other attribute the query would like look `User.query.order_by(User.nickname).limit(5).all()` . But I don't want the first 5 users in alphabetical order, but ordered by their "percentage" amount. And if I change the `User.nickname` to `User.percentage` or `User.percentage()`, it will not work.